# case class to shapeless Generic conversion

Tags: scala, shapeless

***Problem:***

I have a case class `Foo` which can be anything.

I need a function to create a cypher query from this.

The signature of this new function should be

```scala
def createQueryString[T](t: T): String = ???
```

***Example:***

I have `Foo` let's say having two members

```scala
case class Foo(x: Int, y: String)
```

I need it to be converted to cypher

```
CREATE (f:Foo { x: "1", y: "Hello" }) RETURN f
```

If I pass `Foo(1, "Hello")` into the function `createQueryString` mentioned above

```scala
createQueryString[Foo](Foo(1, "Hello"))
```

***What have I tried so far?***

I have tried using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)'s `Generic` and `Aux` to achieve this

```scala
import shapeless._

case class Foo(x: Int, y: String)

def foo[T, HL <: HList](instance: T)(
  implicit gen: Generic.Aux[T, HL]
): HL = {
  gen.to(instance)
}

val myFoo = foo(Foo(1, "Hello"))
s"""CREATE (f:Foo { x: "${myFoo(0)}", y: "${myFoo(1)}" }) RETURN f"""
```

Is there any way I can use this `foo(Foo(1, "Hello"))` to implement inside the `createQueryString` mentioned above? I would want to basically pass types into this function down the road. Somewhat like

```scala
def createQueryString[T](t: T): String = {
  val gen = foo(t) // to get the generic
  s"""CREATE (t: T { x: "${gen(0)}", y: "${gen(1)}" }) RETURN t"""
}
```

Something like this. But by doing this I get the following error

```
Error:(77, 22) could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.Generic.Aux[T,HL]
val gen = foo(t) // to get the generic
```

***Questions:***

1. What am I missing in my last implementation using `Aux`?
2. How can I improve this make it generic enough to incorporate as arguments to the cypher query? There can be more than `x` and `y` in the case class.

Comment: @FahadSididiqui Hey, interesting use case you have there. Have you seen **Neotypes**? Is a **Scala** driver for **Neo4j** _(which I am maintainer of)_. In the project we have a pending [_discussion_](https://github.com/neotypes/neotypes/issues/41) about how to support something like this. Would you like to join the discussion?

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez sure, I will see if I can share my findings on your thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot implicit parameters (or context bounds).

`Generic` can produce not only an `HList` but also a `Coproduct`. That's why if you loose bound `<: HList` compiler doesn't know how to apply `Generic`'s `Repr` to `0`, `1`.

Try

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.At
import shapeless.nat._

def foo[T](instance: T)(
  implicit gen: Generic[T]
): gen.Repr = {
  gen.to(instance)
}

def createQueryString[T, L <: HList](t: T)(implicit 
  g: Generic.Aux[T, L],
  at0: At[L, _0], 
  at1: At[L, _1]
): String = {
  val gen = foo(t) // to get the generic
  s"""CREATE (t: T { x: "${gen(0)}", y: "${gen(1)}" }) RETURN t"""
}
```

If you need labels `x`, `y` then you need `LabelledGeneric` rather than `Generic`.

If you have arbitrary number of parameters then you can transform an HList to desired form and then fold it to a string.

`{ x: "1", y: "Hello" }` looks like a JSON. Look at [Circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/).

Comment: This is good. But the `createQueryString` is again bound for 2 members for the case class. What if we want to handle all range from 1-22 in one function?

I was thinking of implementing some reducer. I can write a reducer extending `Poly2`. However, I am thinking I might need another implicit definition for me to use foldLeft.

Comment: @FahadSiddiqui Why 22? Case classes, HLists and methods are not limited by 22. Yes, you can implement a reducer. Add as many implicit parameters as you need (type classes for work with HLists are here: `shapeless.ops.hlist._`). Or you can transform an HList to an ordinary list of strings (anyway you don't actually use types in HList) and reduce the list.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you are looking for but for your given example, using `Reflection`:

```
def createQueryString[T](t: T): String = {

  def formatFields() = {
  t.getClass().getDeclaredFields().filterNot(_.getName.startsWith("(")).map(f => {
    f.setAccessible(true)
    f.getName + ": \"" + f.get(t).toString + "\""
  }).mkString(", ")
}

val className = t.getClass.getSimpleName
val paramName = nameOf(t)
s"""CREATE ($paramName:$className { $formatFields }) RETURN $paramName"""
```

}

Output:

```
CREATE (t:Foo { x: "1", y: "Hello" }) RETURN t
```

"(" fileters out the constructer and only gives vars/vals.
This code can be tailored to manage nested classes through recursion.

Depndencies:

For reflection support:

`"org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value`

For conveniently getting param name:

`"com.github.dwickern" %% "scala-nameof" % "4.0.0" % "provided"`

On a side note though, this could be one of rare good usecases for using reflection since nothing is being mutated or accessed by any hardcoded value.